# MySQL conf file in MySQL docker

Tags: mysql, ubuntu, docker, mysql-5.7

I am running MySQL 5.7.20 in a docker container created using [the official MySQL docker image](https://hub.docker.com/_/mysql/). The MySQL conf file needs to be mounted on the host Ubuntu system.

Currently the MySQL docker container is started using the command

```
sudo docker run -d \
-p 3306:3306 \
-e MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD=test \
-v /root/test/mysql/var/lib:/var/lib/mysql \
-v /root/test/mysql/etc:/etc/mysql \
--name test-mysql \
mysql:5.7
```

However there are no conf files in `/root/test/mysql/etc`... Connected to the docker container's bash and found that `/etc/mysql` is empty!

Where are the conf files located? Shouldnt there be some in `/etc/mysql/conf.d/` and `/etc/mysql/mysql.conf.d/`?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If you run the command without mounting any volumes:

```
$ docker run -it mysql ls /etc/mysql
conf.d  my.cnf  my.cnf.fallback  mysql.cnf  mysql.conf.d
```

If `/root/test/mysql/etc` **exists** as an empty folder and you mount it onto `/etc/mysql` all the content of `/etc/mysql` will be "replaced" with those in `/root/test/mysql/etc`.

You can have an empty `/root/test/mysql/etc` folder and do the following:

```
docker volume create --driver local \
    --opt type=none \
    --opt device=/root/test/mysql/etc \
    --opt o=bind \
    mysql_vol
```

---

```
sudo docker run -d \
-p 3306:3306 \
-e MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD=test \
-v /root/test/mysql/var/lib:/var/lib/mysql \
-v mysql_vol:/etc/mysql \
--name test-mysql \
mysql:5.7
```

Comment: I tried removing `/root/test/mysql/etc` then start the Docker container using the command stated in the question. `/root/test/mysql/etc` gets created, but it is still empty... Am I doing something wrong?

Comment: Also tried removing `/root/test/mysql/etc`, then started the Docker container using the same command, first without mounting `/etc/mysql`. Then I stopped and removed the Docker container and ran the command containing both `-v` arguments. `/root/test/mysql/etc` gets created now, but is still empty...

Comment: My bad. The first option doesn't work. The directory is getting created empty and is getting mounted onto `/etc/mysql` which makes it empty. The only option is to create the volume and mount the named volume. This will give you the desired effect.

Comment: Tried the second option. Running `sudo docker volume create ...` returned `mysql_vol`. Then I ran the second command `sudo docker run ...`. However the folder `/root/test/mysql/etc` was not created...

Comment: Just create it manually and keep it empty when using this option

Comment: Oops. Created the empty folder `/root/test/mysql/etc`, then ran the 2 commands, but the folder remains empty

Comment: This should work. Do it step by step. `docker volume rm mysql_vol`, delete `/root/test/mysql/var/lib` and the recreate it. Finally run the above commands in the question.

Comment: Works now! Left out `docker volume rm mysql_vol` during previous retries.